# How to reset offset to beginning in spring cloud kafka binder

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring cloud kafka binder to read the data to KStream. While reading the data from one of the topic, i need to read from beginning.

I have tried to set kafka offset reset and start offset properties. But, could not find any references.

Could you please help me providing any sample application.yaml to reset the offset, so that i can consume messages from topic from the beginning

Adding application.yaml that i have used:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input:
  destination: input-topic1
  consumer:
    useNativeDecoding: true
    headerMode: raw
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output:
  destination: output-topic
  producer:
    useNativeDecoding: true
    headerMode: raw
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.beginningInput:
  destination: beginning-topic
  consumer:
    useNativeDecoding: true
    headerMode: raw
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input:
  consumer:
    keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    valueSerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.output:
  producer:
    keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    valueSerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.beginningInput:
  consumer:
    keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    valueSerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    resetOffsets: true
    startOffset: earliest
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder:
  brokers: 127.0.0.1
  zkNodes: 127.0.0.1
  configuration:
    default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    commit.interval.ms: 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

`resetOffsets` was broken. It was reinstated in 2.0.0.RELEASE.

[PR Here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/pull/329).

Comment: i have attached the application.yaml that i have used. I used 2.0.0.RELEASE version. But, still could not see data from the beginning. Is there anything wrong with the configuration i have used.?

Comment: I didn't notice you were using Kafka Streams. My response was about the `KafkaMessageChannelBinder`; it's possible that that it's still an issue with the `KafkaStreamsBinder`. I am not at a computer right now; I suggest you open a GitHub issue, with specific reference to Kafka Streams so the folks that work on that binder can respond.

Comment: Issue opened. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/376